# Trait with Higher-Kinded Types

Tags: scala

Given the following `trait` (from this helpful [shapeless talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDbNxL8bqkY)):

```
scala> trait NatT[F[_], G[_]] { def apply[T](f: F[T]): G[T] }
warning: there were two feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
defined trait NatT
```

I believe this means that `NatT` accepts two higher-kinded parameters: `F` and `G`.

With this assumption, I tried to make an instance where F and G have type `Option`:

```
scala> case object Maybe extends NatT[Option, Option] {
     |   override def apply(f: Option[Int]) = f
     | }
<console>:8: error: object creation impossible, since method apply in trait NatT of type [T](f: Option[T])Option[T] is not de
fined
       case object Maybe extends NatT[Option, Option] {
                   ^
<console>:9: error: method apply overrides nothing.
Note: the super classes of object Maybe contain the following, non final members named apply:
def apply[T](f: Option[T]): Option[T]
         override def apply(f: Option[Int]) = f
                      ^
```

How can I fix this attempt at making a `Maybe` instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `apply` method is missing the type parameter. Simple as that.

```
case object Maybe extends NatT[Option, Option] {
    def apply[A](f: Option[A]): Option[A] = f
}
```

Your attempts to define `apply` without a type parameter are seen as a different method, so it appears that `apply` is unimplemented. Given that `F` and `G` are supposed to be higher-kinds, it doesn't really make sense to try to fix them to `Option[Int]`.